# Derivative with parametric set of equations

Tags: derivatives, parametric, implicit-differentiation

I am struggling for hours on a fairly simple problem. I have the following set of parametric equations:

$$i = I (q_1^2 + q_1 - q_2^2 - q_2)$$
$$v = V (2(q_1 - 1) + \log q_1 - 2(q_2 - 1) - \log q_2)$$

Now I would like to calculate $\frac{di}{dv}$. The canonical way would be to solve the second equation for $q$, plug it into the first and find the derivative. But the second equation is not easily invertible.

So I treat the $q$ as a function of $v$ and take the derivative of the first equation.

Then I take the derivative of the second w.r.t. $q_1$ and $q_2$ and obtain the expressions for $\frac{d v}{d q_1}$ and $\frac{d v}{d q_2}$. Taking the reciprocal value and inserting them into the derivative of the first equation results in:

$$\frac{d i}{d v} = \frac{I}{V}(q_1 + q_2)$$

However, from a paper (and from physical results) I know that the solution must be

$$\frac{d i}{d v} = 2 \frac{I}{V} \frac{q_1 q_2}{q_1 + q_2}$$

I went over it tens of times, tried with Mathematica but the result is always wrong.

Is this approach fundamentally wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re running into trouble because for partial derivatives, which is what you’re really working with here, it’s not generally true that $\frac{\partial x}{\partial y}=\left. 1 \middle/ \right. {\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}}$.

---

One way to attack this problem is to compute $di$ and $dv$, divide one by the other, and try to eliminate the $\mathrm dq$’s:$$
\mathrm di = I((2q_1+1)\;\mathrm dq_1 - (2q_2+1)\;\mathrm dq_2) \\
\mathrm dv = V((2+\left. 1 \middle/ \right. q_1)\;\mathrm dq_1 - (2+\left. 1 \middle/ \right. q_2)\;\mathrm dq_2)
$$
It might make the algebraic manipulations easier by defining $$
\alpha(q_1) = q_1^2+q_1 \\
\beta(q_2) = q_2^2+q_2
$$
so that $$
\mathrm di = I(\mathrm d\alpha - \mathrm d\beta) \\
\mathrm dv = V\left(\frac 1{q_1}\mathrm d\alpha - \frac 1{q_2}\mathrm d\beta\right) \\
\frac{\mathrm di}{\mathrm dv} = \frac I V \frac{\mathrm d\alpha - \mathrm d\beta}{\frac 1{q_1}\mathrm d\alpha - \frac 1{q_2}\mathrm d\beta}
$$
This seems promising. It might also be of use to note that $$\frac{q_1 q_2}{q_1+q_2}=\frac 1{\frac 1 {q_1}+\frac 1 {q_2}}$$

Comment: Oh wow, good input. But what exactly do you mean by "calculating di and dv"? I can only calculate them wrt some variable, eg di/dq1, dv/dq1.

Comment: Another remark following your comment: I can calculate $\frac{di}{d q_1}$ and $\frac{d v}{d q_1}$ and divide them. The result is then also wrong: $\frac{I}{V} q_1$. Same if I do it for $q_2$

Comment: I mean *differentials* instead of derivatives: $\mathrm d i=\frac{\partial i}{\partial q_1}\mathrm d q_1+\frac{\partial i}{\partial q_2}\mathrm d q_2$ and $\mathrm d v=\frac{\partial v}{\partial q_1}\mathrm d q_1+\frac{\partial v}{\partial q_2}\mathrm d q_2$. Re your second comment, dividing by $\frac{\partial v}{\partial q_1}$ runs into the same problem: you need $\frac{\partial q_1}{\partial v}$ for the chain rule, but that’s not $\left. 1 \middle/ \right. {\frac{\partial v}{\partial q_1}}$.

Comment: BTW, are these equations for electronics? The term with the $q$’s in the result reminds me of dynamic resistance.

Comment: Ah ok, you mean the total differential. Sorry, but I am still stuck. If I divide the two expressions ($\mathrm{d}i$ by $\mathrm{d}v$), wouldn't I always end up with something that contains $\mathrm{d} q_1$ and $\mathrm{d} q_2$? Yes electonics, but not dynamic resistance but $q$=charge. They model behavior of a semiconductor.

Comment: The hope is that you’ll be able to eliminate the $\mathrm dq$’s by taking advantage of the independence of the $q$’s (or whatever other relationship might exist between them.

Answer (score 1):

Total differentials are to be used as indicated by amd.

But  makes no sense to me when the right hand side does not involve $ \frac {dq_2}{dq_1}. $

Is some other condition of charge variation missing?

Comment: It does seem like there’s some missing information. After playing around with it a bit, I find that I need $(2q_1+1)\;\mathrm dq_1 = -(2q_2+1)\;\mathrm dq_2$ to get the desired result.

Comment: Then you are on right track, do you need  help to solve this differential equation?

Comment: No, but the OP still might. Seems like the specific question he asked has been answered, though.

Comment: Ok fine,let's wait then

Comment: Great! Indeed, the missing condition was that $\mathrm{d} i_1 = -\mathrm{d} i_2$.

Comment: $ i_1 + i_2 $ is constant , so  physics drives the mathematics here.